# Keeping Lion-style synchronized desktop switching with multi-monitor on Mavericks

Tags: display, macos

Is there a way in Mavericks to get multi-monitor desktop switching behavior similar to (Mountain) Lion?

Example setup:
Thunderbolt monitor + Macbook. Each with three desktops. (1,2,3) & (4,5,6)

Lion:
When swithching desktop from either monitor, the other monitor always switches along to the 'matching' desktop, eg. 1 & 4, 2 & 5, 3 & 6.

Mavericks:
Each monitor's three desktops can switch separately and don't influence the other.

While I definitely see the value of Mavericks' style, I want the old style back. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences > Mission Control, toggle off the "Displays have separate Spaces" setting. That'll switch the behavior back to Mountain Lion's.